# css issue "even height to all the child element in a container"

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

when i click the click button the container 4 overlaps on container 3 its my scenario

**Issue :**
 i had made even height to container 1, container 2, contianer 3 by the `display:flex` i can't achieve it to the container 4, since i used `position:absolute` for the container 4.

the container which contain the max-content will be the `min-height`, so with respect to it all the container should have equal height.

solution can be done by jquery or by css

WORK DONE : http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/wxab9Ldn/14/

**Current output**
[image]

**expected output**

[image]

Comment: its not very clear what you trying to achieve.

Comment: @divy3993 i had posted the screenshot check now

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Zurb Foundation and want to match the heights of all div elements, maybe you can try it by using their helper class "equalizer".

All the docs and examples are here - http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/equalizer.html.

Comment: since iam using `position:absolute` equalizer won't work here. thanks

Comment: Why are you using absolute positioning?

Answer (score 0):

**Check working DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/wxab9Ldn/16/**

Add below script.

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var evenH = 0;
    $('.row .small-4').each(function(){
        var getH = $(this).outerHeight();
        if(getH > evenH)
            evenH = getH;
    });
    $('.row .small-4').css({'height':evenH});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

put this in your css section

```
#main {height: auto;margin:100px 0 0 0;position:relative;display:flex}
    button{padding:0;display:block;position:absolute;right:0px;z-index:111;height:100%}
    .popUp{position:absolute;right:-33.33%}
    .pollSlider{background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);}
    h1{font-size:24px;}
    .row{width:700px:display:table;height:auto;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}
    .small-4,.pollSlider,.first,.second,.delet{display:table-cell;height:100%;overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Comment: .x{
 display:table;
}
.x1,.x2,.x3,.x4{
display:table-cell
}

Comment: thanks for tying out but can u plz work it out with my working demo and post your comments. since its not working still

Comment: as per ur new css  the content at the container 4 not fully displayed some of the contents are hidden check it pls